# Flutter Doctor not recognizing my ANDROID_SDK environment variables

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, dart, android-sdk-tools

I have the android-sdk installed from ubuntu's repository but it does not contain the `sdkmanager`  executable and isn't current enough to be compatible with flutter, so I installed the wrapper from snapd that contains it. According to the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#set-up-your-android-device) I have to change my `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` env. variable so that it works with it. I have also read that I need to set `ANDROID_HOME` to the  directory (I think it's deprecated but just in case) so I put this in my `.profile`:

```sh
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/snap/androidsdk/current/
export ANDROID_HOME=/snap/androidsdk/current/
```

I then ran `source .profile` and restarted my machine, however flutter doctor kept giving me this error:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 27.0.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update the Android SDK visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I know that it's using the wrong path because when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I receive this error:

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found (/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
```

Which points to the path of the the SDK I installed with apt. I have tried `flutter config --android-sdk $PATH_TO_SDK` but that still has not changed anything. Is there a ppa that contains the sdk manager so that I don't have to try and configure flutter to use the snapd androidsdk or is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

androidsdk (snapd) version: 30 (I would prefer not to use this)

android-sdk (apt) version: 25.0.0 (Which is also below flutter's requirements)

Comment: Solution that worked for me, open android studio --> SDK manager and install SDK of 29 level. I hope it will help you as well :)

Comment: @Hamza I would prefer not to install android studio, is there no other way?

Comment: TBH I would strongly recommend you to just install android studio but don't use it. Just keep it because android studio will get you a lot of stuff by default which you don't need to set manually and  this will save a lot of your time. Otherwise you will keep facing such issues regarding SDKs, gradles and emulator etc.

Comment: @Hamza ok that makes sense. Might as well save me the headache, thanks!

Comment: Yes :) And good luck

Comment: @Hamza I uninstalled android studio after installing everything and things seem to work well. Thanks, guess I was being a bit hard-headed haha!

Comment: Oh kay! relax and have a good day sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong path for ANDROID_HOME

Android Studio is not necessary:

After installing flutter with snap and ensuring "/snap/bin" is in your path:

1. sudo snap install androidsdk
2. As regular user: androidsdk "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;30.0.2"

This will install the android sdk tools you need into "$HOME/AndroidSDK"

3. export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/AndroidSDK"
4. flutter doctor

Comment: Ah this very likely could have been the answer. I use Arch linux now and the installation process is much easier, I'll mark this as the answer since it will likely fix it for others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked best for me was to:

1. Install android-studio with `snap install android-studio --classic`,
2. Create an `Android` folder in my home directory and install all the needed components into that folder using android studio and then uninstall android-studio.
3. run `flutter config --android-sdk ~/Android` This configures flutter to use the newly installed Android-sdk located in the home directory.

The advantage of this is that I was able to install the emulator and sdk withut needing to configure anything. The disadvantage is that I'm not sure how the updating process will go, I would have prefered to have used a package manager but this is the easiest way that I have figured out.